# symfony, Missing value for primary key id on QM\backOfficeBundle\Entity\QmEquipe

Tags: symfony

Sorry for my English 
I'm a a novice of programming
and  I have a problem with an application that I am creating for a stage.

my entity is

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
* QmEquipe
*
* @ORM\Table(name="qm_equipe", uniqueConstraints={@ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="prenom_nom", columns={"prenom_nom"}),   @ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="id", columns={"prenom_nom"})})
* @ORM\Entity
*/
class QmEquipe
{
 /**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
private $id;
```

I dont know if whit just this information anyone can help me
Thank you  so much

Comment: Show us the full class code  (without getters and setters) !

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
* QmEquipe
*
* @ORM\Table(name="qm_equipe", uniqueConstraints={@ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="prenom_nom", columns={"prenom_nom"}),   @ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="id", columns={"prenom_nom"})})
* @ORM\Entity
*/
class QmEquipe
{
 /**
  * @var integer
  *
  * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
  * @ORM\Id
  * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
  */
  private $id;
```

Comment: Tx. But with   "@ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")"  yet I have the same error message

Comment: When will you get this error? while generating table? or while inserting the row into table?

Can you please update your question with full entity code with getter and setter method?